Difference between "какой это свитер?" and "что это за свитер?"
What's the difference between какой это свитер? & что это за свитер?

«какой это свитер?» is literally "what kind of sweater is this?", to which the only reasonable answer would be to describe one of its qualities, like «это шерстяной свитер» or «это тёплый свитер».
«что это за свитер?» is a more general inquiry, similar to "what is this sweater?" or even "what about this sweater?", which can be answered, in addition to describing its qualities as above, also with something else, like «это мой новый свитер», «этот свитер мне подарила мама», or «этот свитер -- для тебя».

Maybe another illustrative example could be что это за шум? or что там за шум?, where it's clear that you're asking about the origin or the cause of the noise, and not asking for a mere description in terms of audio characteristics like volume and pitch.

I would say that in you can use both of these in speech. As with many expressions context plays more role here. If we talk about these expressions and their usage in general I would say that что это за свитер? is more natural in everyday speech.
Let's have a look at nuances.

Какой это свитер?

Such a question can be used when you wan to:

know about the object characteristics. For example what material it's made of

- Какой это свитер?
- Это шерстяной свитер


clarify what it's exact sweater. For example your friend has a collection of similar sweaters and you want to ask they which one it is.

- Какой [именно] это свитер [из всех твоих свитеров]?
- Это тот свитер, который мне подарила бабушка на день рождения


Что это за свитер?

As mentioned above, it has a broader context and is more general. You can use it to ask whose this sweater is or about something else. This question is mostly used to clarify what exact sweater it is.
Usually you can use this question when you didn't see something and want to know more about the object.
I've never see this sweater on you before. I want to know more about it:
- Что это свитер?
- Это тот свитер, который мне подарила бабушка на день рождения.

- Что это за свитер?
- Это свитер, который я купил на распродаже.

- Что это за свитер?
- Это тот шерстяной свитер, который мне подарил брат.

Someone found unknown sweater under a bed:
- Что это за свитер? Я нашел его под кроватью.
- Это свитер моего брата, он потерял его, а собака утащила его под кровать. Я верну его брату.


What's the difference between какой это свитер? & что это за свитер?
The difference is the same as between
What kind of sweater is it? And What is it like?
In general there's no difference at all. Answering both questions you describe some quality. Что за is simply colloquial and emphatic
Что за (в вопросе, прямом или косвенном, или в восклицании) — какой? (какая? какое?). Димитрий я иль нет — что им за дело? Пушкин. Что у тебя за страсть кур красть? Что это за напасть такая? Гончаров. — Что у меня за характер!... С женой — и то ужиться не мог. А. Островский. — Голубушка, как хороша! Ну что за шейка, что за глазки! Крылов. Что за вечер! Фет. Что за отчаянные крики. Тютчев.
Источник: «Толковый словарь русского языка» под редакцией Д. Н. Ушакова

not sure why you are downvoted - I do believe this totally makes sense
